# How to get and use the number of each matched line in a global command

Tags: line-numbers, ex-mode

In his (very good) book "Pratical Vim" Drew Neil shows how to collect all the lines containing the word "TODO" into a register to use them latter.

To do so he simply use a global command: `:g/TODO/yank A` (The capital `A` allows to happen lines to the named register `a`).

I think that's a pretty cool trick but I need to improve it: I'm trying to insert the number of the line before it's content. I think the solution would be to get the line number and use it in the last part of the command I mentioned before. The problem is that I don't know how to get this line number.

**So my question is:** How in a global command can I get the number of the matched line and how can I use this number?

Just to be clear here is an example. Let's consider this file:

```
1  //TODO: Hey this is a todo
2  int main(void){
3      //TODO: and this is another one
4      printf("Hello world");
5
6      return 0;
7  }
```

When I type `:g/TODO/yank A` and I put the content of the register in a file I get:

```
//TODO: Hey this is a todo
    //TODO: and this is another one
```

What I would like to get is:

```
1 //TODO: Hey this is a todo
3    //TODO: and this is another one
```

**Bonus** the yank also include the indentation of the line, it would be pretty cool if I could remove it directly from the global command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it:

1. clear the register:

   ```
   :let @a=''
   ```
2. append search results in it:

   ```
   :g/TODO/let @A = getpos('.')[1] . ' ' . getline('.') . "\n"
   ```

Re: BONUS remove indentation in the global command:

```
    :g/TODO/let @A = getpos('.')[1] . ' ' . substitute(getline('.'), '^\s*', '', '') . "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know the `getpos()` and `getline()` commands. Also as you answered the bonus question you deserve a [dancing cookie](http://imgur.com/gallery/j2PQoWh) ;)

Comment: A cookie, yay :)

Comment: @statox Bookmark this: `:help function-list`.  It's a very useful reference.  Also, +1 for the mention of "Practical Vim". :)

Comment: @lcd047: Wow thanks!! I wish I knew this help entry before, that's so nice to have this list here. Vim documentation is really amazing! Also yay I'm pretty new to vim and "Practical Vim" is my Bible at the moment :)

Comment: @Laser also a quickest way to empty the `a` register in normal mode is to record an empty macro with `qaq` maybe it's less elegant than your solution but it works ;) Also your solution can be used in a vimscript whereas I don't think it's possible with mine.

Comment: On a side note: `getpos('.')[1]` is better (and safer) written as `line('.')`.  Also: _always_ specify either `\m` or `\v` in your regexps that are supposed to go into a script (as opposed to the ones you use with `:` commands), to avoid surprises with `magic`.  See `:help \m`.

Comment: @lcd047: I agree with you on the magic switches in regex but I have a question on the `line('.')` command: I understand that it's easier to write and to read but how is it safer? Does this command provides some safety net in case of no matched lines or something like that?

Comment: If you can somehow convince `getpos()` to return an empty list, then `getpos('.')[1]` will fail.  In this particular case it should never happen.  But it's still a good idea to either avoid indices, or add `try ... catch` safety nets.

Comment: I agree about `\m` in a script. You won't make me put the flag in the command line though :) It's bad enough as it is, with magic as default vim search mode, that everybody gives solutions on the Internet in this mode (instead of the `very magic`) - just because it's the default one.

Comment: About using `line('.')` -clearly it is a better solution, even if only because the purpose becomes clearer this way.